# Python - Function does not produce same dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm ultimately trying to plot three combined integrals to where each integral evaluates a certain portion of array `z=np.linspace(1e+9,0)`

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplab as plt
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate as integrate

z = np.linspace(1e+9, 0, 1000)
mass = 1000
Omega_m0 = 0.3 
Omega_L0 = 0.7 
h = 0.7


def FreeStreamLength(z, mass, Omega_m0, Omega_L0, h):
    kb = 8.617e-5 ## kev K^-1 
    c = 3e+5 ## km/s
    T0 = 2.7 ## K
    T_uni = mass/kb

    a = 1./(z+1.)

    z_nr = T_uni/T0 - 1. ## redshift at non relativistic   
    a_nr = 1/(z_nr + 1.) ## scale factor at non relativistic  

    Omega_r0 = (4.2e-5)/h/h
    a_eq = Omega_r0/Omega_m0
    z_eq = 1/a_eq - 1

    a1 = a[a <= a_nr] ## scale factor before particles become non-relativistic
    a2 = a[a_nr <= a.all() <= a_eq] 
    a3 = a[a_eq <= a] 

    integrand = lambda x: 1./x/x/np.sqrt( Omega_m0/x/x/x + Omega_L0 ) 

epoch_nr = [ c/H0 *integrate.quad(integrand, 0, i )[0] for i in a1]
epoch_nreq = [c/H0/a_nr * integrate.quad( integrand, a2, a_eq )[0] ]
epoch_eq = [c/H0/a_eq * integrate.quad( integrand, i, 1 )[0] for i in a3]
return epoch_nr + epoch_nreq + epoch_eq
```

`z` should pass through `a`, so effectively, these values should correlate with one another.

For the `return` line I combined all the lists to create this new array for my function.

```
FSL = FreeStreamLength(z, mass, Omega_m0, Omega_L0, h)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(z, FSL, color="blue", label=r"$z=0$")
plt.show()
```

I'm returned with `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

How come my new list does not match with the list I had before?

I believe it has to with how i'm iterating out elements from the passed array before I defined the integrand in my function.

Comment: I can't run your script because `T_uni` and `T0` are not defined

Comment: @gsmafra Sorry about that, I edited our the irrelevant part that is causing it. So try it again.

Comment: I still can't run your code without making guesses and corrections!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do there, but when you index an array of booleans to another array in python you get an array with the elements where the array of booleans are True.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
>>> b = np.asarray([True,False,True])
>>> print(a[b])
array([1, 3])
```

That is what's happening in this line

```
a1 = a[a <= a_nr] ## scale factor before particles become non-relativistic
```

Also, here

```
epoch_nr + epoch_nreq + epoch_eq
```

you are adding three lists (two of them have length 1). When you do this you get those lists appended and the result will have the length of those 3 lists summed:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1]
>>> c = [1]
>>> a + b + c
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clear about where the error occurs, but I'm guessing that the `x` and `y` in the error message correspond to the `z`, `FSL` inputs to `plot`.  Have you printed the shape of those 2 variables?  While you are at it, check their `dtype`.

I expect, from `z = np.linspace(1e+9, 0, 1000)` that `z` is (1000,) float.

But what is `FSL`?  The indentation of your function is off, but I'm guessing it is `epoch_nr + epoch_nreq + epoch_eq`.  I would say the sum of 3 arrays, but no, those are lists.  So it's the concatenation of 3 lists.

So is the total length of this list `len(a1)+1+len(a3)`?

We shouldn't have to step through your code guessing at what happens at each step.  That's your job.  When you have dimension problems in `numpy` start printing the shape at any suspected points in your code.  Don't guess at what the shape should be!  Verify it.

---

OK, I jumped the gun and tried running your code.

What is `a_nr <= a.all() <= a_eq` supposed to do?

```
a2 = a[(a_nr <= a) & (a <= a_eq)]
```

but that makes `len(a2)` 4 and `len(a3)` 1, which messes up the `epoch_nreq` integral (with `a2` boundary).